# Opening and Using .tif and .twf files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geolocation, geotiff-tiff

I have in the same folder .tif and .twf files with the same names. How should I open them in QGIS correctly? If I select add raster layer and add the .tif file, would that be enough? Would QGIS also consider the .twf file? And how can I understand if it is correctly geolocated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's enough. `.twf` is the [world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) for `.tif` files.

QGIS will read it when you open your `.tif` raster file.

Use a basemap like OpenStreetMap or other vector files that describe lands, countries, etc. located at the same place as your `.tif` for verify the location. OSM is configured by default, [look at this](https://www.spatialbias.com/2018/02/qgis-3.0-xyz-tile-layers/) for find how to open the OSM basemap (XYZ Tiles in the **Browser Panel**).

Or just check coordinates, if you know them. You can use [this kind of site](https://app.dogeo.fr/Projection/#/point-to-coords) to verify the coherence between coordinates and CRS (coordinate system).